# Why the variable is undefined in the method but it is not in the constructor in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm developing an application using 1.4.9 Angularjs with Typescript.

I have a controller which have the testManagementService service injected, the testManagementService variable is an object in the constructor, but it is undefined in the method where it is invoked. The odd thing is that, I have the same setup in another controller with another service and it is working fine.

Issue:

- there is a console.log in the constructor with the label testmgmgservice, it says the testManagementService variable is an Restangular object having the getTestSuiteTree method
- the console log in the readRepository method, which is called by / managed by kendo.data.TreeListDataSource, says that this.testManagementService is undefined.

[image]

What I did so far:

- I have checked the syntax, it is possible I have missed something --> no
- I have changed the variable name something different to check whether there is some other variable which overwrites it --> the same result
- I had a long sleep, sometimes help --> there is no new idea
- I have compiled the code with both Vs2013 and VS2015 --> same result

**the service**:

```typescript
module sayusiando.gonogo.web.spa.service {
    import IGeneralTestSuitTestCaseContract = sayusiando.gonogo.web.spa.common.contracts.IGeneralTestSuitTestCaseContract;
    "use strict";

    export interface ITestManagementService {

        getTestSuitTree(): ng.IPromise<IGeneralTestSuitTestCaseContract[]>;

    }

    class TestManagementService implements ITestManagementService {

        //#region ctor
        constructor(
            private Restangular: restangular.IService
        ) { }
        //#endregion

        public getTestSuitTree(): ng.IPromise<IGeneralTestSuitTestCaseContract[]> {

            var resource = this.Restangular.all("TestSuite/GetTestSuiteTree");

            return <any>resource.getList();

        }

    }

    factory.$inject = ["Restangular"];

    function factory(Restangular: restangular.IService) {
        return new TestManagementService(Restangular);
    }

    angular
        .module("goNoGo")
        .factory("testManagementService", factory);

}
```

**The controller**:

```typescript
module sayusiando.gonogo.web.spa.mainpage.showtestsuittree.controllers {
    import IGeneralTestSuitTestCaseContract = sayusiando.gonogo.web.spa.common.contracts.IGeneralTestSuitTestCaseContract;
    import DataSourceTransport = kendo.data.DataSourceTransport;
    import DataSourceSchema = kendo.data.DataSourceSchema;
    import DataSourceSchemaModelFields = kendo.data.DataSourceSchemaModelFields;
    import TestManagementService = sayusiando.gonogo.web.spa.service.ITestManagementService;
    "use strict";

    export interface IShowTestSuitTreeController {
        activate: () => void;
    }

    class ShowTestSuitTreeController implements IShowTestSuitTreeController {

        //#region Variables
        testSuiteTree = [];
        testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions: kendo.ui.TreeListOptions = {};
        //#endregion

        //#region Inject and ctor
        static $inject: string[] = ['testManagementService'];

        constructor(
            private testManagementService: gonogo.web.spa.service.ITestManagementService
        ) {

            console.log('testmgmgservice', testManagementService);

            this.activate();

        }
        //#endregion

        activate(): void {

            var dataSourceTransport = <DataSourceTransport>{
                read: this.readRepository
            };

            var schema: DataSourceSchema = <DataSourceSchema>{
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    parentId: "parentId",
                    fields: <DataSourceSchemaModelFields>{

                        id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                        name: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true }

                    }

                }

            };

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                transport: dataSourceTransport,
                schema: schema,
                batch: true
            });


            var idColumn: kendo.ui.TreeListColumn = <kendo.ui.TreeListColumn>{
                field: "id",
                width: "100px"
            };
            var nameColumn: kendo.ui.TreeListColumn = <kendo.ui.TreeListColumn>{
                field: "name",
                width: "400px"
            };

            this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.dataSource = dataSource;
            this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.sortable = false;
            this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.editable = false;
            this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.columns = [
                idColumn,
                nameColumn
            ];

        }

        readRepository(e): any {

            console.log('testmgmt2', this.testManagementService);
            this.testManagementService.getTestSuitTree().then((result: Array<IGeneralTestSuitTestCaseContract>): void => {
                e.success(result);
            }, (reason: any): void => {
                e.error(reason);
            });

            return e;
        }

    }

    angular
        .module("goNoGo")
        .controller("showTestSuitTreeController", ShowTestSuitTreeController);
}
```

**The generated javascript from the controller**:

```js
var sayusiando;
(function (sayusiando) {
    var gonogo;
    (function (gonogo) {
        var web;
        (function (web) {
            var spa;
            (function (spa) {
                var mainpage;
                (function (mainpage) {
                    var showtestsuittree;
                    (function (showtestsuittree) {
                        var controllers;
                        (function (controllers) {
                            "use strict";
                            var ShowTestSuitTreeController = (function () {
                                function ShowTestSuitTreeController(testManagementService) {
                                    this.testManagementService = testManagementService;
                                    //#region Variables
                                    this.testSuiteTree = [];
                                    this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions = {};
                                    console.log('testmgmgservice', testManagementService);
                                    this.activate();
                                }
                                //#endregion
                                ShowTestSuitTreeController.prototype.activate = function () {
                                    var dataSourceTransport = {
                                        read: this.readRepository
                                    };
                                    var schema = {
                                        model: {
                                            id: "id",
                                            parentId: "parentId",
                                            fields: {
                                                id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                                                name: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                                    var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                                        transport: dataSourceTransport,
                                        schema: schema,
                                        batch: true
                                    });
                                    var idColumn = {
                                        field: "id",
                                        width: "100px"
                                    };
                                    var nameColumn = {
                                        field: "name",
                                        width: "400px"
                                    };
                                    this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.dataSource = dataSource;
                                    this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.sortable = false;
                                    this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.editable = false;
                                    this.testSuiteTreeKendoTreeListOptions.columns = [
                                        idColumn,
                                        nameColumn
                                    ];
                                };
                                ShowTestSuitTreeController.prototype.readRepository = function (e) {
                                    console.log('testmgmt2', this.testManagementService);
                                    this.testManagementService.getTestSuitTree().then(function (result) {
                                        e.success(result);
                                    }, function (reason) {
                                        e.error(reason);
                                    });
                                    return e;
                                };
                                //#endregion
                                //#region Inject and ctor
                                ShowTestSuitTreeController.$inject = ['testManagementService'];
                                return ShowTestSuitTreeController;
                            })();
                            angular
                                .module("goNoGo")
                                .controller("showTestSuitTreeController", ShowTestSuitTreeController);
                        })(controllers = showtestsuittree.controllers || (showtestsuittree.controllers = {}));
                    })(showtestsuittree = mainpage.showtestsuittree || (mainpage.showtestsuittree = {}));
                })(mainpage = spa.mainpage || (spa.mainpage = {}));
            })(spa = web.spa || (web.spa = {}));
        })(web = gonogo.web || (gonogo.web = {}));
    })(gonogo = sayusiando.gonogo || (sayusiando.gonogo = {}));
})(sayusiando || (sayusiando = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=showTestSuitTreeController.js.map
```

Comment: I think the problem can be related to "this" and is reference. Have you tried to log it in your readRepository function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you are passing the function reference to the framework here:

```
  var dataSourceTransport = <DataSourceTransport>{
      read: this.readRepository
  };
```

Doing this, you are losing the context (the this). When the library calls your readRepository function, it no longer works on the context you defined the function beforehand. So, the `testManagementService` does not exist on `this` when the function is called.

You can fix this, by binding to the correct context like so:

```
  var dataSourceTransport = <DataSourceTransport>{
      read: this.readRepository.bind(this)
  };
```

or by capturing this using an arrow function when passing the reference

```
  var dataSourceTransport = <DataSourceTransport>{
      read: (e) => this.readRepository(e)
  };
```

or by making the callback an arrow function itself, keeping the registration as is. Be aware of the implications, as the function then is no more registered on the prototype.

```
readRepository = (e) => {
    ...
}
```

For more info, please check https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html